# sync Project Browser Pane with edited file in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I'm trying to use WebStorm for its debugging ability and want to sync the Project Browser Pane with the file I m editing. Both sublime and eclipse offer some way to do this but I can't seem to find the option in ws.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Alt+F1 (Navigate | Select In...) on file in Editor, choose Project View from the list.
Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: sorry, not sure I follow you... what do you mean by 'staying in sync'? I thought that you were looking for a possibility to select currently opened file in the Project View...

Comment: in eclipse you select a button and whatever file you point to in the tab highlights in the project pane

Comment: @Shanimal Yes -- in Project View panel, under settings (cog icon) activate **Autoscroll from Source**

Comment: @LazyOne if you want to put that down as an answer I'd be happy to ++ This was the spirit of the question and the answer I was really looking for. either way... thanks!